# Linux rename multiple files

Tags: linux, rename

I have some files named in a specifc pattern, for example, `ab_2000_1.jpg`. In this name `2000` is representing years and `1` representing month(1 means january). I have a 20 years of monthly files like this.

Now I want to rename every one of them into the following format `ab_2000_1_12.jpg`, `ab_2000_2_12.jpg`, etc

I know how to rename files using `rename` and `sed` command. But I want to know how can I loop this command for all files.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: how do you determine the month and day (_1-12, _2_12) ? from metadata of the file?

Comment: Start by getting a filelist with what ever shell you are using, bash, zsh, csh. And grab the filename inside the loop.

Comment: @Ron my files are named based on year and month only. There is no "day" parameter. The "12" in the file name is sort of an ID of my files. And so this ID will remain constant in all filenames

Comment: @kometen mean something like: ```for i in $(ls); do echo "${i}"; done``` The variable ```${i}``` is what you need for ```rename``` and ```sed```.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for` loop to loop over all file names matching a pattern as `for file in pattern; do some_commands; done`.

You don't need `sed` to modify the file name in this case. A variable substitution like `${variable%pattern}` will remove the shortest string matching `pattern` from the end of the variable value.

The following example code will remove `.jpg` from the end of the file name and append `_12.jpg` to the result.

```
for file in ab_*_*.jpg
do
   mv "$file" "${file%.jpg}_12.jpg"
done
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I learned something new. But I am looking for a substitution of required years and months in command like `for file in AVEARCHM_*.a; do  mv ab_${year}_${month}.jpg dd.${year}_${month}_12.jpg"; done`. Where year={2000..2009}, month={1..12}

Comment: @linux_lover My answer is based on the requirements in your question as it was when I wrote the answer. From your comment I do not understand what you mean with "substitution of required years". Your search pattern does not match the arguments of the `mv` command. The only difference I can see is that you seem to replace a leading `ab_` with `dd.`. Please make all your requirements clear **in your question**. Show an example of existing files and expected result of renaming.